# Sinon does not mock provided URL for GET with parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, sinon

I am trying to develop test for my services in Angular app and facing some issues with it.

Here is the service code:

```
/**
 * Sends http request to get client states and territories available for specific vertical
 *
 * @param {number} vertical id of specific vertical. The following mapping is used:
 *    0 - Federal
 *    1 - State
 *    2 - Local
 *    3 - Education
 * @returns {Observable<State[]>} array of state objects with its display name and value as observable
 */
getClientsStatesByVertical(vertical: VerticalEnum): Observable<State[]> {
  let params = new HttpParams();
  if (vertical != null) {
    params = params.append('vertical', String(vertical));
  }
  return this.http
    .get(`${CLIENT_API_ENDPOINT}/csr/states`, {params: params}) as   Observable<State[]>;
}
```

Here is my test:

```
it('#getClientsStatesByVertical with vertical provided', (done) => {
  const expectation = [{label: 'Georgia', value: 'GA'}];
  server.respondWith('GET', `${CLIENT_API_ENDPOINT}/csr/states?vertical=${VerticalEnum.Federal}`);
  const o = service.getClientsStatesByVertical(VerticalEnum.Federal);
  o.subscribe(response => {
    expect(response).toEqual(expectation);
    done();
  });
  server.respond();
});
```

I am getting the following error when I am running this test using karma:

```
HttpErrorResponse: Fake server request processing threw exception: Http failure response for http://localhost:19000/api/v1/clients/csr/states: 404 Not Found
```

Could you please point me to the issue, seems that I am missing smth simple, cause almost the same cases with shorter URLs are working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I forgot to add response into respondWith function :)

```
server.respondWith('GET', `${CLIENT_API_ENDPOINT}/csr/states?vertical=${VerticalEnum.Federal}`, JSON.stringify(expectation));
```

it solved the issue